# Second Modal position at body with vertical scrollbars (Bootstrap Modal)

Tags: jquery, css, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I've a problem with the position of a second modal in a body with y-scrollbars. I am using Bootstrap 3.4.2 (in combination with AdminLTE).

The first modal ist positioned correctly: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKWNd.png).

But the second modal seems to be moved a bit to the right side...
(the second modal is opened by click on the blue button in the first modal): 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWN4b.png).

Modals are "standard" and opened by data-toggle/target in a  tag:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="renamePlayer" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Rename Player</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">  
        <table class="table">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td class="col-md-2">Player:</td>
            <td class="col-md-8"><span id="player"></span></td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class="col-md-2">Amount:</td>
            <td class="col-md-8"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="amount" placeholder="1" maxlength="3"></td></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">CLose</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="some_id" >Some description</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I assume that this has something to do with the scrollbars of the body? But i dont know how to fix it.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!
Sicksnape

Comment: You can check the pixel difference using browser inspect element tool..did u try that?

Comment: Hi,
I haven't done that. Which information from the inspect tool should I check?

Comment: if in chrome 2 icons will appear on top left. https://ibb.co/8PkKHCt

Comment: Ah - yes I did that. The size of the boxes itselves are ok. the problem is that the second modal moves to the right because when the first modal opens it's centered (center is calculated including the body scrollbar). When the first modal is opened the scrollbars are "away" (because the body gets the open modal class and hides the scrollbar). So the second modal calculates the "new center" which is not directly over the first modal :( That's my assumption...